# How can I get the sum, difference, quotient, product of two values and printed out in textview

Tags: java, android-studio, math

I'm making a simple calculator and I'm having trouble with four basic operations. How do I program it so that when I put one value, then use one of the operations, then put another value, I get the answer?

I've tried different solutions but this is the one I'm on right now

```
        Button btnD = findViewById(R.id.buttonD);
        Button btnM = findViewById(R.id.buttonM);
        Button btnS = findViewById(R.id.buttonS);
        Button btnP = findViewById(R.id.buttonP);

        btnD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int a = 1;
                int b = 2;
                int q = a/b;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. Click this comment to find out how to provide what we need to help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a question that is answerable?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions so you will be better prepared and able to ask a question that will be well received and more importantly **answerable**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add two EditText for getting two numbers then add four button for different operation like add/sub/mul/div. Get value of editText and Set onClickListener and write appropriate code in that.

```
EditText firstNumber;
EditText secondNumber;
TextView addResult;
Button btnAdd;

double num1,num2,sum;

firstNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNumber1);
secondNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNumber2);
addResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResult);
btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        num1 = Double.parseDouble(firstNumber.getText().toString());
        num2 = Double.parseDouble(secondNumber.getText().toString());
        sum = num1 + num2;
        addResult.setText(Double.toString(sum));
    }
});
```

something like that.

Comment: May you show an example? It's much easier for me to understand that way.

Comment: what are the id's txtNumber1, txtNumber2, txtResult supposed to represent?

Comment: this is the id of your editText. @RayaanAfzal

Comment: so can I just replace txtNumber1 with firstNumber?

Comment: this is autogenerated brother you so you cant replace it with txtNumber.

Comment: how come it's not showing autogenerated for me then?

Comment: it is the name of the widget so when you declare the widget that widget name you have to write here. when you compile the project .R file automatically generate the id of that widget. @RayaanAfzal

Comment: read this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_user_interface_controls.htm